# Cambiar el mismo código de c++ a java

Tags: java, c++

¿Cómo puedo expresar el siguiente código de c++ en el lenguaje java?

```
int **ptrarray_relocation = new int* [number_rows];
    for (int count = 0; count < number_rows; count++)
        ptrarray_relocation[count] = new int [number_columns];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo con @Sioesi aunque el modificador de acceso `public` depende de de dónde se declara.

Seguramente ése código se está ejecutando desde un método, por lo que los modificadores de acceso generarían error de compilación; hay dos formas de escribir ése código:

*Asumiendo que estamos dentro de algún método*

### 1

```
int[][] ptrArrayRelocation = new int[number_rows][];

for(int i = 0; i < number_rows; i++){
  ptrArrayRelocation[count] = new int [number_columns];
}
```

### 2

```
int[][] ptrArrayRelocation = new int[number_rows][];

for(int[] fila : ptrArrayRelocation){
  fila = new int [number_columns];
}
```

Comment: elimine la mia y me quedo con la tuya, ya que es mas completa y respecto al modificador de acceso concuerdo contigo! Saludos